# Обработка события еще не созданного объекта

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Здравствуйте, никак не могу разобраться с input-ом. Мысль такая:

1. Есть контейнер `var main2 = document.getElementById('main2')` которого слушает `addEventListener`
2. В процессе идет создание через innerHTML `<div> <input type="text"> </div>` которые помещаются в этот контейнер (main2)

**Вопрос:**
Как повесить обработчик *(желательно чтобы он реагировал на "Enter")* на `input`, если изначально его не существует в дереве?

**Важно:** обработчик прямо в разметке, в атрибуте, который называется on<событие>.(`<input type="text" onclick="countRabbits()"`) - не работает;[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

***БЕЗ JQuery!***

---

Comment: где определена функция `countRabbits`, и почему она не находится?

Comment: создавайте нормальные DOM элементы(`createElement`), без `innerHTML` и будет Вам счастье

Comment: Функция в самом конце `function countRabbits() { console.log('Hi');}`

Comment: @Aleksey разбирайтесь, почему функция не видна - она, случайно, не внутри другой функции, кириллица не попала в с, о, а?

Comment: @Igor да вы правы, весь код был написан внутри самовызывающейся функции `(function (global) { ... } (window));`. Но почему так получается? И как совместить оба эти метода?

Comment: @Aleksey у Вас `countRabbits` не видна из глобальной области видимости `window.countRabbits = function() { console.log('Hi'); };`

Comment: Спасибо, надо будет почитать про это)

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов, это вынести добавление инпута в отдельную функцию и навешивать обработчик там

```
function createInput(parent, cb) {
    const input = document.createElement('input');

    // делаем еще че-нить с инпутом
    input.onсhange = cb; // либо прямо в функции прописать обработчик

    parent.appendChild(input)
}
```

А потом где то в коде создавать эти инпуты

```
const main2 = document.getElementById('main2')
createInput(main2, function (e) {
    console.log(e);
})
```

Comment: А второй из вариантов - использовать всплытие событий, обрабатывая их на уровне контейнера.